# Webjob Invocations Separate AppDomains

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

There is a scenario in one of our continuous webjobs which has us a little puzzled. We have very thorough logging and the picture that it paints seems to indicate that two messages were dequeued by the same invocation of a webjob. The timestamps seem to support this. But more compelling was the exception.

At one point in our code we are adding a key to a dictionary. The exception that we observed was that a duplicate key was attempted to be added to that dictionary. If the 2 messages were dequeued at the same time by the same instance of the webjob method, then that is the only thing that seems to make sense. Because the dictionary is created with each invocation using the **new** keyword i.e. each invocation of the dequeue method creates a separate object in memory.

In short, my question is, can 2 messages be dequeued simultaneously by the same instance/method of a continuously running webjob which is observing that queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there is parallel execution so the ordering of the dequeued messages would be different. You can set the batchsize to 1 https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/#config

Comment: Thanks. That looks interesting and as we are already using a JobHostConfiguration object, we could configure it some more. However, I downloaded a blob from a loggapp container which is a csv file that confirms the same Pid and instance id of the job were used for two messages. That is consistent with the dictionary duplicate key exception that we are seeing for those two messages. The dictionary is not a static member of the class. It is new’d up in the method which dequeues messages. Any way to ensure separate instances, and thus, separate dictionary objects?

Comment: Can you please post a snipped of your function definition for the QueueTrigger

Comment: I believe I have identified the bug. The dictionary is inside a class called StateService. Whilst the StateService is new’d up during every invocation of the queue trigger, the dictionary inside that StateService is a static member of that class. Basically, Re-sharper would have suggested that it be static and I would have inadvertently alt-entered it. Because I did not intend it to be static. But still my fault, of course. Thanks for the help and for the excellent tip in your answer.